# Open all the hyperlinks inside the default browser

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to use Emacs to manage my `bookmarks` for Firefox. I just want to store them inside `a simple shared text file`. From what I see, `org-mode` seems very close to what I want, I write an `URL`, this is detected by `org-mode`, the `URL` is clickable and open a new tab inside Firefox. So far so good.

There is a small list of websites that I check frequently:

- Is there a way to open the `URL` of the `buffer` in one time? (click or `elisp` function)
- Preferably, is there a way to open all the `URL` of a sub-part of the `buffer`? (paragraph, prefix, etc)

An idea of such file:

```
My daily links:
http://link1
http://link2
http://link3
http://link4

My weekly links:
http://link5
http://link6
http://link7
http://link8
```

Or maybe, if it's more easy to implement:

```
[1] daily links and [2] weekly links:
[1] http://link1
[1] http://link2
[1] http://link3
[1] http://link4
[2] http://link5
[2] http://link6
[2] http://link7
[2] http://link8
```

Comment: for your first question, you could map one of the keys of org-mode to browse-url, for instance

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-o") 'browse-url)

Comment: and for your 2nd question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767779/is-there-an-apply-command-to-each-line-in-region-in-emacs - with do-lines you can call browse-url on each line

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to BrunoO, I have been able to do the following:

```
(defun do-lines (fun &optional start end)
  "Invoke function FUN on the text of each line from START to END."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (while (< (point) end)
      (funcall fun (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
      (forward-line 1))))

(defun do-open-urls ()
  (interactive)
   (if (use-region-p)
       (do-lines 'browse-url (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (do-lines 'browse-url (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Comment: Assuming it answered your question, you can accept your own answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it is an org file, then you can place links in the file, and they will be click-able. See the **Hyperlinks** section of the org manual. Worth looking at because there is a nice way you can associate a description with the address.

Instead of just saying:
http://someplace.on.earth

You can say:
[[http://someplace.on.earth][Important Site]]

Which will show up as a clickable link called "Important Site".

I am guessing the behavior you want is to be able to click on the link, and have your browser open to that page. I *think* this is the default behavior. You can
look at the variable **browse-url-browser-function** and specify the behavior you like.

Next step, you can look at the **org-cliplink** package - it provides a simple command that takes a URL from the clipboard and inserts an org-mode link with a title of a page found by the URL into the current buffer.